# Select a column if other column is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to select a field called ProgramID from a table and if the ProgramID is NULL then I need to select the value in the InterimProgramID from the same table and alias it as ProgramID.

How can I make a conditional SELECT statement to do this?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You need the ISNULL function.

```
SELECT ISNULL(a, b)
```

`b` gets selected if `a` is null.

Also, you can use the WHEN/THEN select option, lookup in BOL. Essentially: its c switch/case block meets SQL.

Comment: MySQL equivalent is IFNULL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: and its `a || b` in javascript

Comment: PostgreSQL equivalent is NULLIF https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF

Comment: I mean the question is strictly tagged for tsql

Comment: @PeterAronZentai That doesn't mean people won't find this if looking for this same problem for other SQL variants. And Postgres equivalent is actually `COALESCE`

Answer (score 44):

```
  select COALESCE ( ProgramID , InterimProgramID ) as 'ProgramID'
```

Comment: This solution seems to answer the question best

Answer (score 28):

You can use either the [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function or the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function. They both do pretty much the same thing, however `ISNULL` only takes two parameters and `COALESCE` takes multiple parameters (returning the first non-null it encounters). Both try the first param, then the second, (and COALESCE continues on)

```
DECLARE @IAMNULL VARCHAR
DECLARE @IAMNOTNULL VARCHAR
SET @IAMNOTNULL = 'NOT NULL'

SELECT ISNULL(@IAMNULL, @IAMNOTNULL)
--Output: 'NOT NULL'

DECLARE @IAMNULLALSO VARCHAR

SELECT COALESCE(@IAMNULL, @IAMNULLALSO, @IAMNOTNULL)
--Output: 'NOT NULL'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also:

```
Select NVL(Column_A, Column_B) From 'schema'.'table_name'
```

The NVL( ) function is available in Oracle, and not in MySQL or SQL Server. This function is used to replace NULL value with another value. It is similar to the IFNULL Function in MySQL and the ISNULL Function in SQL Server.

https://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-nvl.html

Comment: Question is tagged for TSQL and SQL Server, so...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ProgramID
  FROM a_table
 WHERE ProgramID IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT InterimProgramID AS ProgramID
  FROM a_table
 WHERE ProgramID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce('zzz-' + ProgramID, InterimID) as programID will still ignore ProgramID even if you have a pretext value. It's a cool little function

Answer (score -1):

You can also use IFNULL function

```
select IFNULL(ProgramId,interimId) as ProgramId
```

Comment: This question is about SQL Server and `IFNULL` does not exist with that DBMS, only `ISNULL`