# How to create a 3rd column based on 2 columns from two tables [inner and outer join]

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, inner-join, outer-join

- I have a lot of rows in 'table alpha' where some of these rows occurs in 'table beta' as well.
- Both row alpha and beta have a date column.

  - However, when i select both date columns the rows from table alpha **that do not occur** in row B will have a null-value assigned to them.

> My problem is that I want to make a third date-column that will use the dates from table *beta* **if they are not null**. If they are null, it should use the dates from table alpha.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9878541/1624583

Comment: Show us sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: Awesome, the link Dhwani posted did the job for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not provided any info about your data model. I have given you a rough draft based on your problem.

```
Select 
colA,
colB,
...,
alpha.date1,
beta.date2,
COALESCE(beta.date2,alpha.date1) date3
from 
alpha
left outer join beta (your keys)
```

Comment: You should look into `COALESCE` and save yourself a lot of time (and complexity) typing out long `CASE` statements.

Comment: ya thats a better option :) @TomH

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any good data example (db schema) and expected result

Here is my approach:

```
SELECT 
   a.date,
   COALESCE(b.mycolumn, a.mycolumn)
FROM alpha a
LEFT JOIN beta b
ON a.date = b.date
```