# ISNULL get the data from another column

Tags: t-sql, case

If the email column is NULL, I want to have the phone number value in the PRIMARY_Contact column. I am using CASE expression, but could not do it properly.

Comment: This is very vague. Please show the code you tried and show the error message you got if you got one,

Comment: @dfundako 

'select [CustomerID], EmailAddress, 
   case 
   when EmailAddress is null then [Phone] as Primary_Contact
   from[SalesLT].[Customer]'

Comment: `ISNULL(EmailAddress, Phone) as Primary_Contact`

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much @JoshPart

Comment: You're welcome. Also, [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878523/select-a-column-if-other-column-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `COALESCE`.  It will return the first non-null value from a selection.  It's actually just shorthand for `CASE`, but may be easier for you to implement.

In your example, perhaps that would look like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(EMAIL,PRIMARY_CONTACT)
```

Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx for more details.