# IF in SELECT Clause

Tags: sql-server-2012

How can I return one column or another depending of its value?

I have the following stored procedure (this is just an example):

```
SELECT 
    Stds.FirstName, 
    Addrs.Address 
FROM
    Students AS Stds 
INNER JOIN 
    Address AS Addrs ON Addrs.StdId = Stds.StdId 
GROUP BY 
    Addrs.FirstName, 
    Stds.Address
```

Now the idea is that `Addresses` have two fields: `Address` and `AddressTwo`, I want to return `AddressTwo` **IF** `Address` is `NULL` for that `Student`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for my particular case, and maybe in general I wanted to use ISNULL().

Response here:
[Select a column if other column is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878523/select-a-column-if-other-column-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE`, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    Stds.FirstName, 
    COALESCE(Addrs.Address, Addrs.AddressTwo) AS Addr
FROM 
    Students AS Stds INNER JOIN Address AS Addrs ON Addrs.StdId = Stds.StdId
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below sql.

```
SELECT 
    Stds.FirstName, 
    case when Addrs.Address is null then AddressTwo else  Addrs.Address end Address 
FROM
    Students AS Stds 
INNER JOIN 
    Address AS Addrs ON Addrs.StdId = Stds.StdId 
GROUP BY 
    Addrs.FirstName, 
    case when Addrs.Address is null then AddressTwo else  Addrs.Address end
```